# Rewriting Proxy setup from Nginx conf file to Apache conf file

Tags: apache, proxy, nginx

i was trying to find a solution on the internet, but with no success. I need to rewrite nginx proxy conf commands to apache commands. I need to send sites starting with "login" and "logedas_" to port 81 on the same server.

Nginx conf

```
    location = /login {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81 ;
    }

    location /logedas_ {
        access_log off ;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81 ;
    }
```

I've just writen this to my apache conf file, but it doesn't work :/

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
<Proxy *>

Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /login http://127.0.0.1:81
ProxyPassReverse /login http://127.0.0.1:81
ProxyPass /logedas_ http://127.0.0.1:81
ProxyPassReverse /logedas_ http://127.0.0.1:81
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In Apache config, the ProxyPass does not support the special case you've used in nginx config, so you should use:

```
ProxyPass /login http://127.0.0.1:81/login
```

and

```
ProxyPass /logindas_ http://127.0.0.1:81/logindas_
```

instead.